# how to clear the vscode terminal when I run the code again?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, settings

Is there a way in Visual Studio Code to clear the previous code in the terminal every time I execute the code. It's very annoying to type `clear` every time I wanna run the code again (or to run another file).

Comment: I assume you can edit the Build script?

Answer (score 1):

To clear Terminal in VS Code simply press Ctrl + Shift + P key.
type command Terminal: Clear.
go to View in taskbar upper left corner of vs code and open Command palette.
I think Ctrl + K should do the trick too if you are in windows, or else you can make shortcuts for clearing the terminal using VS Code shortcuts(keybindings file).